# OPENCOBOLIDE INSTALLATION - arch linux

Tags: linux, gnucobol, arch

yaourt installation process doesnt work on me so i used

```
sudo pip3 install OpenCobolIDE --upgrade
```

I installed Python3, PyQt5, GnuCOBOL and pip for Python3.

but this error shows

```
Using cached OpenCobolIDE-4.7.6.tar.gz (12.9 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: OpenCobolIDE
  Building wheel for OpenCobolIDE (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-cdgayzvo/opencobolide_77d831079fdb4feb97e8a17b215ebc75/setup.py", line 61, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError("This setup.py does not support wheels")
      RuntimeError: This setup.py does not support wheels
      [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for OpenCobolIDE
> Running setup.py clean for OpenCobolIDE
> Failed to build OpenCobolIDE
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for OpenCobolIDE, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

TO install opencobolIDE.

Answer (score 0):

In any case: remember that [OCIDE is out of maintenance since 2017](https://github.com/OpenCobolIDE/OpenCobolIDE/issues/439).
If you want a COBOL specific IDE (so not want to use vscode with COBOL extensions) you may want to have a look at building [Gix-IDE](https://github.com/mridoni/gix/blob/main/doc/building_and_installing.md#linux-1) instead.

Then: the yaourt installation with `yaourt -S opencobolide` is the preferred one, so if an another version doesn't work I highly suggest to not fix that, but the preferred one. What does "doesn't work" mean?

Finally to the pip error: build without wheels is likely what you want: `sudo pip3 install --no-use-wheel OpenCobolIDE`